# How long does it take for a balloon to deflate?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinematics, ideal-gas, equilibrium, gas

Since gas flows from an area of high pressure to low pressure, upon opening an aperture on say a balloon one would expect the contents to diffuse out until both the inside and outside reach a pressure equilibrium.

I was wondering if there is any way to **quantitatively** determine the rate at which this occurs, presumably modeled by some function of time.

I've attempted to find a solution online, but I can't seem to find anything quantitive. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but this model require some differential equations. Can you sketch some of them?

Comment: Can we assume that there is a small pipe attached to the balloon at its neck?  Can we assume that we know the non-linear stress-strain properties of the balloon rubber membrane comprising the balloon?