# What theoretical equation can be applied to the a graph that compares the area of the hole of the balloon to the its time of floating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I have done experiments regarding balloon hovercrafts. I have changed different sizes for the exit hole of my hovercraft and have measured the time it floats.

this is a graph I have done.
[image]

I know this looks directly proportional, but is there any thoeretical equation that can explain why I got these results?

Comment: Related (and unanswered): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370867/25301

Comment: You would need to know the [pressure in a balloon as a function of radius](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pressure+balloon+radius&client=ubuntu&hs=npy&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvp7fBxPbhAhXFJDQIHanVBPIQ_AUIDigB) and [air flow through an orifice vs. pressure](https://www.google.ca/search?q=air+flow+orifice+pressure&client=ubuntu&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiduMioxfbhAhWtJjQIHYMJAfsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1203&bih=645). Neither has a simple formula.